# Adding horizontal lines before and after a link element

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following look of the Read More button:

[image: Screenshot]

I have everything **except for the lines** that are next to the read and more words, for which I used before and after pseudo elements.

What would be the best approach to add the lines?

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.read-more {
  background: red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px 0px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px 0px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px 0px #aaa;
}
.read-more::before {
  content: "read";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -3.2rem;
  margin-top: -0.75rem;
}
.read-more::after {
  content: "more";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -3.2rem;
  margin-top: -0.75rem;
}
.read-more img {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.60rem;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.15rem;
}
```

```html
<a class="read-more" href="#">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT5el.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make this as semantic as we can:

- decorative images in the CSS
- link text in the HTML
- pseudo elements to create those lines
- `em` units to keep everything spaced out nicely

With these in place, we can achieve a great result with a single HTML element:

```
<a href="#">Read More</a>
```

### Demo

The negative `text-indent` along with the `word-spacing` work together to place the "Read More" text around the background image.

`@media` is used to increase the lines length when the viewport gets wider

```css
a {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: #E20025 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT5el.png) center no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  text-indent: -3em;
  word-spacing: 4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #E20025;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}
a:before,
a:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #CCC;
  width: 7em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  top: 1.5em;
}
a:before {
  left: -11em;
}
a:after {
  right: -11em;
}
/*Modify @media as required*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 515px) {
  a:before,
  a:after {
    width: 9em;
  }
  a:before {
    left: -13em;
  }
  a:after {
    right: -13em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 570px) {
  a:before,
  a:after {
    width: 10em;
  }
  a:before {
    left: -14em;
  }
  a:after {
    right: -14em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  a:before,
  a:after {
    width: 12em;
  }
  a:before {
    left: -16em;
  }
  a:after {
    right: -16em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  a:before,
  a:after {
    width: 17em;
  }
  a:before {
    left: -21em;
  }
  a:after {
    right: -21em;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Read More</a>
```

Comment: Hi, this is really cool! The only problem I see with this is that the button is placed on a responsive web. When the viewport is enlarged, the side lines looks too short. Can they be responsive as well and stretch fully (except for 20 padding of the wrapper)?

Comment: This solution is elegant and short, why wrap it in a `span` and make it more complicated? wouldn't it be better for @VeryCurious to add some CSS to adapt the `a:before` and `a:after`  to different screen sizes instead?

Comment: That would look like a logical solution to me (but I'm no expert :$). @VeryCurious must have `@media` or similar defined in the CSS (some responsive design is mentioned) so it would be easy for him/her to add some extra code for the link. Imho it is beautiful the way it is (at least HTML-wise)

Comment: Well, there are already another lines in the site used to divide sections. It is eye catching when the lines are not aligned on the sides. If I use @media, I am afraid, it will always look kinda messy... I would preder a neat look.

Comment: @VeryCurious - `@media` is a neat solution, the trick is to get the ratio right for each size. You could put a `min-width` for every 10 pixels if you wanted to have finer control over it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for suggestion! I appreciate ur help very much. I will try the @media.

Comment: You're welcome! There will be a perfect combination of different widths, just need to do the maths :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can using "content". You could use a "border" element before and after, or do it with JavaScript.:

```
jQuery("href").append("<hr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/8gv76802/2/)

Code

HTML

```
<div id="wrapperdiv">
  <div id="somediv"></div>
  <a class="read-more" href="#"><img src="..."/></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapperdiv {
  position: relative;
}
#somediv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.read-more {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  ...
}
.read-more::before {
  ...
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.read-more::after {
  ...
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: The line is not splitted, it can be seen behind the circle.